# RxAndroidBle: BleDisconnectedException: Disconnected from MAC='XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX' with status 0 (GATT_SUCCESS)

Tags: android, rx-java2, bluetooth-gatt, rxandroidble

I'm working on an application that uses your framework and I faced into the next issue after my phone connected with ble device after few seconds:

```
com.polidea.rxandroidble2.exceptions.BleDisconnectedException: Disconnected from MAC='XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX' with status 0 (GATT_SUCCESS)
```

I use the next implementation of connection:

```
public Observable<Boolean> establishConnection(@NonNull String macAddress) {
        RxBleDevice device = mRxBleClient.getBleDevice(macAddress);
        return device
                .establishConnection(false)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnNext(rxBleConnection -> mRxBleConnection = rxBleConnection)
                .flatMap(rxBleConnection -> Observable.just(true));
    }
```

where result of `establishConnection` is:

```
Disposable establishConnectionDisposable = bleManager
                .establishConnection(mMacAddress)
                .subscribe(aBoolean -> bleManager.readServices(mMacAddress), throwable -> {
                    Log.e(TAG, throwable.toString());
                    onBackPressed();
                });
mCompositeDisposable.add(establishConnectionDisposable);
```

Well, the reason of disconnecting isn't crear for me. Could someone help me to figure out?

Comment: Did you find the solution here ?

Comment: @Hunt, Unfortunately not. The issue is still happening.

Comment: @T_Anton_T any updates? Did you solve it?